# Unable to login to unix server using Plink in batch ifle

Tags: unix, batch-file, autosys

we are facing one issue with Plink while running the batch files, we are running batch files using `autosys`, the batch files are available in my windows client server and one of the batch file will call the plink to connect the unix server but we are facing the issue to connect the unix server, when I run the batch script using command prompt then the plink can be connected the unix server but it is not happening with `autosys` to run the batch scripts. below is the Plink command...

```
call %aScrDir%plink -l %hypSrvUser% -pw %hypSrvPwd% %essSvr% "sh /xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

when we see the error file which is generated by autosys there are some errors

```
"The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.

The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:

    ssh-rsa 2048 f9:5e:2a:4a:11:ed:40:91:80:3a:13:04:08:05:e7:ac

If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) Connection abandoned."
```

could you please give the suggestion to avoid this situations and where do we add the host key in the server.

appreciate your action on this.

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1* : If allowed, first start a manual connection to the server and confirm the SSH key

*Option 2* : If you are running the last version, there is a `-hostkey` switch to indicate in command line the expected host key

*Option 3* : Use something like

```
echo N | %aScrDir%plink -l %hypSrvUser% -pw %hypSrvPwd% %essSvr% "sh /xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

That is, pipe the `n` character to the plink command to answer `no` to the query to save the host key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we have small doubt with above code after run this code echo N | %aScrDir%plink -l %hypSrvUser% -pw %hypSrvPwd% %essSvr% "sh /xxxxxxxxxxx"  code if we run the batch file using Autosys next time what will happen  will it run the batch using autosys or give the same error again.

Comment: Yes I have run the above code but no luck, we have not got anything after run the code manually in command prompt.it just connect the unix server then exit to command prompt, could you please suggest other way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it would be working fine.

cd to the plink.exe file directory

```
echo Y | .\plink.exe -pw xxyyxxyy root@host_ip 'ls -lah'
```